# Get interchange name from Google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps JS API.
I can see the interchange names on free highways on zoom >=14.
Next code shows "Nesharim Interchange": http://jsfiddle.net/Monya/Qh66j/

```
function initLocation(location){
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.915437867851846,34.90520650818826),
        zoom: 21,
        scaleControl: true,
        scaleControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
        }
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    initLocation(homeLatLon);
    drawPolyline();
});
```

How can I get all interchange names using Google Maps API?

Comment: 1. you can't (legally) get _all_ the interchange names using the API (but review the [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos) for yourself).  2. That data doesn't seem to be available from the reverse geocoder.

Comment: **geocodezip**, thanks a a lot!
If so, how can I get at least **one** interchange name using API? For example the name of on Latlng (31.915437867851846,34.90520650818826). Any info in any way is very appreciated!

Comment: I talked to MAPA which are the map data provider for GOOGLE maps, they said they don't have this data, so GOOGLE creates these point according to some strange algorithm. That's why there are so many errors in interchange names.